# How do I execute Magento 2 CLI commands using a custom script?

Tags: magento2.3, permissions, cli, script, command-line

I had created a custom script which update my database. After completion of database update, I want to execute the Magento CLI commands by adding custom functions in my custom script.

The script should run commands as below:

```
1) setup:upgrade
2) content:deploy
3) reindex
4) flush
5) 777 permissions for var/ pub/ generated/ Directories
```

How could I do it using a custom script in Magento 2.3.x?

Answer (score -1):

Just call the terminal commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:f
chmod -R 777 var
chmod -R 777 pub
chmod -R 777 generated
```

Comment: I know that how to run commands via custom script. But I want to run the commands using custom php script along with database update script.

Comment: why not just use shell_exec php command to run those?